# How to overcome simulation of ode issue in R?

Tags: ode

I@m trying to solve and then optimise the parameter and initial condition values in the system of differential equations. However, I can't run the code due to error messages (this code was working fine when the FS was given as an equation). Due to the limited data points, I want to be able to optimise against E values the whole system (calculated using equation F). I've made the code work till the LLode function, so optimisation doesn't take place at all. 
I've managed to solve the error thanks to forum replies (Lyngbakr):

```
initSim<-ode(initCond, tspan, hormonesode, params, method="ode45",atol = 1e-10, rtol = 1e-10,hmax=NULL,maxsteps=100000000000000000)
```

Warning message:

> In rk(y, times, func, parms, method = "ode45", ...) :
>         Number of time steps 1 exceeded maxsteps at t = 0

I will appreciate any hint.

Malgosia

My code looks as follow:

```
tspan<-c(0,1,2,3,4,5)#,6,7,8,9,16,17,18,19)
E<-c(0.303,0.205,0.205,0.381,0.272,0.188)#,0.317,0.274,0.106,0.161,0.947,2.722,4.701,0.24)

names(df)=c("tspan","E")
require(deSolve)

#initial parameter values

#k1<-1.062169#0.370 7.754
k2<-1.908891#-0.00727284 0.022
#k3<-0.321
k4<-2.14
k5<-10.7
#k6<-1.07
A0<-1.38 #15.47
B0<-0.61 #0.298
C0<-0.28
#F0<-0.303#3.28803757 3.434

#define a weight vector outside LLODE function
wts<-sqrt(sqrt(E))
#combine parameters into a vector
params<-c(k2,k4,k5,A0,B0,C0)
names(params)<-c("k2","k4","k5","A0","B0","C0")
#ode function
hormonesode<-function(t,x,params){
  A<-x[1]
  B<-x[2]
  C<-x[3]
  D<-x[4]
  E<-x[5]
  F<-x[6]
 # k1<-params[1]
  k2<-params[1]
  #k3<-params[3]
  k4<-params[2]
  k5<-params[3]
  A0<-params[4]
  B0<-params[5]
  C0<-params[6]



 P<-3.02796-3.1867*cos(0.314159*t)-0.55332*cos(2*0.314159*t)+0.362678*cos(3*0.314159*t)+0.486708*cos(4*0.314159*t)-0.10133*cos(5*0.314159*t)-0.21977*cos(6*0.314159*t)-0.08926*cos(7*0.314159*t)+0.222292*cos(8*0.314159*t)-1.05119*sin(0.314159*t)+0.855633*sin(2*0.314159*t)+0.176677*sin(3*0.314159*t)-0.05658*sin(4*0.314159*t)-0.34108*sin(5*0.314159*t)-0.15718*sin(6*0.314159*t)+0.397642*sin(7*0.314159*t)-0.0986*sin(8*0.314159*t)   
 FS<-0.1944+0.002017*cos(0.261799*t)+0.009603*cos(2*0.261799*t)+0.01754*cos(3*0.261799*t)+0.106208*cos(4*0.261799*t)+0.020423*cos(5*0.261799*t)+0.015417*cos(6*0.261799*t)+0.01079*cos(7*0.261799*t)+0.115042*cos(8*0.261799*t)+0.008853*sin(0.261799*t)+0.013523*sin(2*0.261799*t)+0.012254*sin(3*0.261799*t)+0.026053*sin(4*0.261799*t)+0.000957*sin(5*0.261799*t)-0.001*sin(6*0.261799*t)+0.002374*sin(7*0.261799*t)+0.026775*sin(8*0.261799*t)
   dA<-1.0621*1/(1+(1/5*P)^5)*(1/3*(F^10)/(1+(F)*1/3)^10)-2.14*A; 
  dB<-75*(((A/5)^10)/(1+(A/5)^10))-8.56*B; 
  dC<-1.909*FS+0.321*FS*C- 0.749*C; 
  dD<-0.749*C- 0.749*D+0.214*FS*D^2; 
  dE<-0.749*D-0.749*E+0.214*B*E^2; 
  dF<-k2 + k4*D + k5*E-1.07*F; 
  output<-c(dA, dB, dC, dD, dE, dF)
  list(output)
}

#Initial conditions

A0<-2500#1.0038#2.794
B0<-105#25.0061#6.13
C0<-0.018#0.02#0.06126
D0<-0
E0<-0
F0<-0.303#3.28803757 3.434

initCond<-c(A0, B0, C0, D0, E0, F0)
initCond

#run ode with initial guesses
initSim<-ode(initCond, tspan, hormonesode, params, method="ode45",atol = 1e-1, rtol = 1e-1,hmax=NULL, maxsteps=100000)
plot(tspan,initSim[,7], type="l", lty="dashed")
points(tspan,E)
initSim
LLode<-function(params){


  A0<-params[4]
  B0<-params[5]
  C0<-params[6]
  D0<-0
  E0<-0
  F0<-0.303


  initCond<-c(A0, B0, C0, D0, E0, F0)

  #Run the ODE
  odeOut<-ode(initCond,tspan,hormonesode,params,method="ode45",atol = 1e-1, rtol = 1e-1,hmax=NULL, maxsteps=100000)
  if(attr(odeOut,"istate")[1]!=0){
    #Check if satisfactory 2 indicates perceived success of method 'lsoda', 0 for
    #'ode45'. Other integrators may have different indicator codes
    cat("Integration possibly failed\n")
    LL<-.Machine$double.xmax*1e-06#indicate failure
  }else{
    y<-odeOut[,7] #measurement variable
    wtDiff1<-(y-E)*wts#weighted difference
    LL<-as.numeric(crossprod(wtDiff1))#Sum of squares

  }
  LL
}

# optimize uzing optim()
MLoptres<-optim(params,LLode,method="Nelder-Mead",
                control=list(trace=0,maxit=500))
MLoptres


require(optimx)

optxres<-optimx(params,LLode,lower=rep(0,6),upper=rep(200,6),
                method=c("nmkb","bobyqa"),
                control=list(usenumDeriv=TRUE, maxit=500,trace=0))
summary(optxres,order=value)
bestpar<-coef(summary(optxres,order=value)[1,])
cat("best parameters:")
print(bestpar)
#dput(optxres,file='includes/C20bestpar.dput')
bpSim<-ode(initCond,tspan,hormonesode,bestpar,method="ode45")
X11()
plot(tspan,initSim[,7],type="l",lty="dashed")
points(tspan,E)
#points(tspan,MLoptres[,]/k,type="l",lty="twodash")
points(tspan,bpSim[,7],type="l")
title(main="Improved fit using optimx")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As it stands, it’s impossible to answer your question due to lack of information: There are dozens of possible reasons for this and we can only guess. Please [edit] it to include an [mcve]. Also add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: What does your model definition look like? Have you tried another method (e.g., `lsoda`)? As @Wrzlprmft says, we need a MCVE. Also, you may be asking for too much precision. Try increasing `atol` and `rtol`, too.

Comment: Where's parameter `k1`? It's included in `params`, but never defined.

Comment: Hi Lyngbakr, I've tried that too. This code was working when I've put a value of FS as a differential equation. However, I want to improve the model solution and parameterization, so I want to input as many data as I have to be able to optimise remaining parameters. I've tried to increase atol and rtol but with not luck.

Comment: Your model runs fine up until a time of 1.8. (Try `tspan<-seq(0,1.8, by =0.05)`.) `A` appears to be increasing dramatically over time and, I suspect, is the root of problem. I think it ultimately increases so fast that the required time step is smaller than machine precision. You need to look at the structure of the model and the model parameters, and ask *why* you see this explosion.

Comment: Thank you Lyngbakr for your help. I've got a bit further after playing with initial values for hours and reduction of tspan. However, the optimisation doesn't take place, it still runs into the problems, Is there any chance to overcome that or I just have to continue playing with initial conditions till I will get it to run? I've edited the code, I've embedded also the part of code responsible for optimisation. Would be great if you would get a chance to look at that.

Comment: At this point, I don't think it's coding issue, but rather a conceptual issue. As I say, I think you need to consider the structure of the model and the values of the parameters you use and ask why they are not realistic, as presumably this sort of behaviour isn't observed in reality. Models reflect our imperfect understanding of the universe and results such as these can help guide you towards where the misunderstanding lies. I think the model is behaving as defined, so if this is not realistic you need to figure out what's wrong with your definition or conceptualisation.

Comment: Thank you Lyngkbark. Yes, the initial values are unrealistic, but the system was solved so I thought wrongly that parameterization will as well, finding more realistic values. I'll try to get through the values once again and maybe I will be luckier. Thanks again.